# create event observer for new attribute save action of product

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, admin, product-attribute

I want to create an event observer  when admin create a new attribute or save existing attribute from admin panel. I have not found any suitable event observer.  Please can help me??

Answer (score 1):

Try using `eav_entity_attribute_save_before` or `eav_entity_attribute_save _after`.

It could also work with `catalog_entity_attribute_save_before` or `catalog_entity_attribute_save_after`.

Comment: Thank for your response. I actually save data to another table when click on **Save Attribute** or **Save and Continue Edit** button in magento admin panel under categog->Attributes->Manage Attribute.